# Exception when using boost::serialization and binary format

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I'm trying to implement lazy reading through boost::serialization. It was easy to save/load std::vector, but that require reading the whole vector in one go, which wasn't really feasable when having a large number of objects.

My idea was to store the object count as the first object in the archive and then just keep adding geopoints at the end of the file. If you have a better idea I'm all ears.

The writer class appear to work and the reader get the right value as count in the constructor, but then it crashes when trying to read a GeoPoint using operator>>, on this line:

```
archive >>p;
```

With the output:

```
Stream writing 1.25, 3.2
Stream writing 2.5, 6.4
Stream writing 3.75, 9.6
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  input stream error
```

Here's an SSSC illustrating my problem:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>

using namespace std;

struct GeoPoint {
    GeoPoint() : lon(0), lat(0) {}
    GeoPoint(float _lon, float _lat) : lon(_lon), lat(_lat) {}
    float lon;
    float lat;
};

namespace boost {
    namespace serialization {
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive& ar, GeoPoint& point, const unsigned version) {
            if (version == 1) {
                ar & point.lon;
                ar & point.lat;
            }
        }
    } //serialization
} //boost
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(GeoPoint, 1);

class PointReader {
public:
    PointReader(const std::string& path)
        : stream(path.c_str(), ios::in), archive(stream), read(0) {
        archive >>count; //count as the first object in the archive
    }
    PointReader& operator >>(GeoPoint& p) {
        archive >>p; //Crash and then the BT goes into boost files
        ++read;
        return *this;
    }
    bool is_good() {
        return read < count;
    }
private:
    uint32_t read;
    uint32_t count;
    std::ifstream stream;
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive archive;
};

class PointWriter {
public:
    PointWriter(const std::string& path)
        : filepath(path), stream(path.c_str(), ios::out), archive(stream), count(0) { }

    ~PointWriter() {
        if(stream.is_open())
            close();
    }
    void close() {
        stream.close();
        stream.open(filepath.c_str(), ios::out);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive out(stream);
        out <<count; //write new count as the first object in the archive
        stream.close();
    }
    PointWriter& operator <<(const GeoPoint& p) {
        archive <<p;
        ++count;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    std::string filepath;
    uint32_t count;
    std::ofstream stream;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive archive;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    PointWriter streamw("foo2.data");
    for(int a = 1; a < 4; ++a) {
        GeoPoint p;
        p.lon = float(a*1.25f);
        p.lat = float(a*3.2f);
        cout <<"Stream writing " <<p.lon <<", " <<p.lat <<endl;
        streamw <<p;
    }
    streamw.close();

    PointReader streamr("foo2.data");
    uint32_t loops = 0;
    while(streamr.is_good()) {
        GeoPoint p;
        streamr >>p; //Crash
        cout <<"Streamr read " <<p.lon <<", " <<p.lat <<endl;
        if (++loops > 10)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming you have boost installed in /usr/include you can build it using this command:

```
g++ -o sssc sssc.cpp -I/usr/include/ -lboost_serialization
```

Comment: The buffer is not flushed correctly in PointWriter - in close(), comment out the first 3 lines, then serialize to `archive` as in `archive << count`. This way the archive gets written correctly. There is a problem with the archiving of the `count` variable - it gets placed at the end of the archive, not the beginning, I believe.

Comment: But the reader get the correct value when reading count. If I just write to archive, won't that put it at the end?

Comment: I tried commenting out the first line, then you append the count, not replacing the current count in the file, and the reader sees it as having 0 items.

Comment: I'll post when I have time again, but omit the first 3 lines in `close()` - up to the declaration of the `boost::archive::binary_archive object`. Then write to the archive member object in the next line. No need to close the stream. You'll find the archive gets written to properly, with the count at the back. Then the PointReader fails as it tries to read `count` as the first item. Eliminate *that*, and the whole thing works fine. Tip: use `text_iarchive` and `text_oarchive` to see what is going on - it will be clear. As for a fix, I'm thinking about it.

Comment: Having looked at this, I think your best bet is to keep the struct count in a separate archive - boost serialization is not built for random access to  and that's what it would take. Eliminating your `close()` method makes the above code work, without an object count.

Comment: Yea I've begun leaning toward the same conclusion, it's made to be read and written serially. I'll take a look at other serialization frameworks, it'd be nice to have the count in the same file. Thanks a lot for taking the time.